# How to launch emacs in console on Catalina?

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs, macos-catalina

Before updating to Catalina, I was using emacs in the terminal. When I updated to Catalina, emacs was no longer found. So, I installed it with Homebrew. Now, emacs launches in a GUI, its own window. How can I get the 'emacs' command running emacs in the terminal again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flag `-nw` is always used to start emacs in a non-GUI mode. So, you'd use `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw`. Note that this is a Ruby wrapper around the Emacs binary, so on Catalina you may have to allow full disk access to Ruby as detailed in [this Emacs.SE post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/how-to-restore-file-system-access-in-macos-catalina).

Comment: Just saw this, thank you so much!! I didn't have to do anything special - just "emacs -nw filename". Thank you! :)

Comment: Following up on this, how to remap option to hyper and command to Meta. I tried almost everything. I also would rather to only change the mapping for when running emacs in the terminal and not to all terminal mappings.

Comment: @SFbay007 you should post that as a new question.